# php form passing array as parameter

Tags: php, html

I'm passing an array in parameter in a php form but it doesn't work, any help please.

In step1.php:

```
$groupinfo['groupname'] = "test";

<form name="GroupAdd"  method="post" action="Step2.php5?groupinfo=<?php echo serialize($groupinfo); ?>">
```

IN step2.php:

```
$groupinfo = unserialize($_GET['groupinfo']);
```

and

```
echo $groupinfo['groupname'];
```

display nothing;

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: some problem when posting ... the text is truncated

Comment: How do you pass the parameter, show the real code ?

Comment: Here you are, i have pb when posting

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO and to all that qualify that is off-topic because of I have a problem when posting, the code is truncated. The post is edited 2mn after to correct the problem. So could you change your vote about this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it `Step2.php` or `Step2.php5`? It doesn't seem like your form is calling the right script. In addition, the result of a `serialize()` should be properly escaped to be included in a URL, by using `rawurlencode()`.

But giving the client the oportunity to have your script running `unserialize()` in something inputted by him can be a serious **security breach**. Don't ever do that.

The proper way of doing this would be either by using `http_build_query()` to convert your array into an HTTP query string, or using tags `<input type=hidden>` to forward those values in the POST body.

```
<form name="GroupAdd" method="post" action="Step2.php5">
<?php

    foreach ($groupinfo as $k => $v)
        printf('<input type="hidden" name="%s" value="%s">', rawurlencode($k), rawurlencode($v));

?>
...
</form>
```

Comment: i'll try your code. (php5 is the extension i have to put in my platform in order to active php5 - i call the right script)

Comment: rawurlencode() doesn't work with character in utf8 ... For example rawurlencode('Trần') ... provide 'Tr%E1%BA%A7n%20' when I get the value. I have tried encode_utf8(rawurlencode('...')) but it doesn't work because of the string is already in utf8 i think.

Comment: I replace rawurlencode by htmlspecialchars and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [http-build-query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) (in your first step)

```
$groupinfo = array('groupID' => 1, 'groupname' => 'test');
$qStr = http_build_query($groupinfo); // groupID=1&groupname=test
```

Build the Form action like this

```
<form name="GroupAdd"  method="post" action="Step2.php?<?php echo $qStr ?>">
```

On the second step (get it from the url)

```
echo $_GET['groupname'];
```

You can also use

```
$urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
parse_str($urlParts['query'], $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: I'll try ... and keep you inform .. thanks

Comment: it works only with the second parameter groupname, groupID is not passing. When i do echo $_GET['groupID'] nothing is displaying. And the second option parse... doesn't work.

Comment: echo $_GET['groupname']; works well

Comment: Well, glad to know that it works but why the second option is not working ? I'm not sure but it should work.

Comment: @NhuPhung, you are right, second one should not work.

Comment: @NhuPhung, I've updated the answer but `echo $_GET['groupID'];` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="GroupAdd"  method="post" action="Step2.php5">
    <input type=hidden name=groupinfo value="<?php 
    echo addslashes(serialize($groupinfo)); 
                                              ?>">
    <input type=submit>
```

then in step2

```
$groupinfo=unserialize($_POST['groupinfo']);
```

alternatively

```
<form name="GroupAdd"  method="post" action="Step2.php5">
<?php
foreach($groupinfo as $key=>$value)
{
echo "<input type=hidden name='$key' value='$value'>\n";
}
?>
<input type=submit>
```

which would have the same result as Recovering since 2003's build query

Comment: it doesn't work ... :( nothing display